# ActiveRecord Query on text field PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table Products and around 58000 records in it. I run two queries are as follows.

```
Product.where(description: 'swiss').count
```

It returns **0** products out of **58000** products. But when I run query below.

```
Product.where.not(description: 'swiss').count
```

it returns **2932** products out of **58000** products. I think it should return all **58000** products, because it is the reverse of first query. 
I did not understand why it returns only **2932** products.

Comment: I think your description field consist values other than "swiss" also. Check the value 'swiss' because postgresql is interpret "swiss" and "Swiss" differently.

Comment: @SachinR yes when i put 'Swiss' it returns 291 products. but in this case it should also returns all 58000 products.

Comment: Product.select(: description).distinct this return all distinct descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have NULL values in your columns, this could happen, because `NULL` always compares as `NULL`, even to itself, but `WHERE` expression must be true to include a result.

```
'a' = 'a'; True
'a' = 'b'; False
'a' = NULL; Results in NULL (not false!)
NULL = NULL; Results in NULL (not true!)
'a' != 'a'; False
'a' != 'b'; True
'a' != NULL; NULL
```

e.g. consider the table `null_test` containing

```
 id | str
----+-----
  1 | <NULL>
  2 | a
  3 | b
```

When looking for a column equal to some value, the `NULL` is never equal, so this will just return row 2.

```
SELECT id FROM null_test WHERE str = 'a';
```

But the same applies looking for a column **not** equal to some value, the `NULL` is never not equal (its NULL), so this will just return row 3.

```
SELECT id FROM null_test WHERE str != 'a';
```

Thus the total of your `=` and `!=` is not all the rows, because you never included the `NULL` rows. This is where `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` come in (they work like you might expect `= NULL` and `!= NULL` to work).

```
SELECT id FROM null_test WHERE str != 'a' OR str IS NULL;
```

Now you get rows 1 and 3, making this the opposite of `str = 'a'`.

For `ActiveRecord`, it treats the Ruby `nil` value like the SQL `NULL` and creates the `IS NULL` checks in certain situations.

```
NullTest.where(str: 'a')
SELECT * FROM "null_test" WHERE "str" = 'a'

NullTest.where.not(str: 'a')
SELECT * FROM "null_test" WHERE "str" != 'a'

NullTest.where(str: nil)
SELECT * FROM "null_test" WHERE "str" IS NULL

NullTest.where.not(str: nil)
SELECT * FROM "null_test" WHERE "str" IS NOT NULL

NullTest.where(str: nil).or(NullTest.where.not(str: 'a'))
SELECT * FROM "null_test" WHERE "str" IS NULL OR "str" != 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have likely many records where `description` is `nil` and those are not included in the `not`.

A way to include the 'nil' records as well would be...

```
Product.where('description <> ? OR description IS NULL', 'swiss')
```

Or alternatively

```
Product.where.not(description: 'swiss').or(Product.where(description: nil))
```